# Get class prop name in php

Tags: php, properties

I'm not good at php OOP.

```
class Example{
    public $name;
    public $age;
}

$example = new Example();
```

I would like to get the property name as string, like-

```
echo get_property_name($example->name); //should echo 'name'
//OR,
echo $example->name->toString(); //should echo 'name'
```

Please note that, I don't want to **write** the property name in a string or variable like-

```
$property = $class->getProperty('name');
```

I don't want to get the value of property, I want to get the name of the property as a string.

Is it possible in php?

Comment: You may want to look at https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php

Comment: Despite the comments and answers, I don't think that is possible. When you're doing `$example->name`, you're getting the property value, not the property. Anyway, you need to know its name to use it. You can use `ReflectionClass::getProperty` to get a property, or a `ReflectionProperty`, which has the method `getName`.

Comment: @PedroAmaralCouto I am also thinking that it's not possible in php.

Answer (score 0):

You can build a helper function with get_object_vars(). Because you already know the var-name, the function only checks, if this exists in the object and returns the var as string:

```
function get_property_name($oObject, $sString) {
  $aObjectVars = get_object_vars($oObject);
  if( isset($aObjectVars[$sString]) ) {
    return $sString;
  }
  return false; // object var not exists
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you can introspect a class, function, or... with ReflectionClass:

```php
<?php


class Example
{
    public $name;
    public $age;
}

$example = new Example();

$ref = new ReflectionClass($example);

$props = $ref->getProperties();

foreach($props as $prop) {
    var_dump($prop->name);
}
```

The output:

```
string(4) "name"
string(3) "age"
```

Comment: What if I want an specific property i.e. only the "age" ?

Comment: It seems that something is wrong! If have string 'age' and you want 'age', actually you have it. You can use `->` in order to get the value of properties.

Comment: I don't want to get the value of property, I want to get the name of the property as a string.

Comment: The `var_dump` function dumps the type and you can get rid of type by simply assigning the `$prop->name` to a variable or using `echo` to see its value.

Comment: Use `echo $name . "\n";` instead of `var_dump(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

one other option would be a trait with following methods.

```php
public function toArray(): array
{
    return (array) $this;
}

public function properties(): array
{
    return array_keys($this->toArray());
}
```

We do not know your use case. If you write a DTO, Reflection might be your desired way. If you write a model with some extra sugar, you could store all attributes in an array to load and edit them. Probably two arrays so you could compare edited and loaded values. with `__isset`, `__get`, `__set` you can always preload attributes.